# Response DTO with file within

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have some question. Can you actualy return file within dto, or it is impossible?
If it possible, how can I do it correctly in Spring rest controller?

For example:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getData", produces = "???")
public ResponseEntity<DtoWithFile> getData() {
    // Some logic
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new Dto("name", 21, myFile));
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DtoWithFile {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private ???? file;
}
```

I have tried to add Resource, custom MultipartFile, byte[]
And excepted that I will get reponse dto and download file

Comment: Can you add the raw bytes and serialize them to JSON? Sure. Will the web client recognize it as a file download? No. To do that, you have to send a response with the correct headers, containing *only* the file and no additional DTO or fields.

Comment: Thank you. I will add another endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. It is possible to return a file in JSON (or XML, CSV... as long as it's a textual datatype) by encoding the file in a base64 string and setting it in your DTO as a field.

This a classic approach, but beware of some performance shortcomings. Mainly in terms of memory as the whole file will be loaded in memory as `byte[]` at some point, which can be pretty problematic depending on the type of file and server load.

Here is some documentation on how to do it : [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode)

Otherwise, you can create another endpoint with a `Resource` and proper mime-type.